# Python multiprocessing: Why does using Process run my program from the start?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I was having some trouble figuring out why my console would always print the print statements I had at the start of my file. Here's what it looks like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

print('hello')  # why does this get printed over and over again?


def func1(num):
    print(num ** 2)
    time.sleep(1)


def func2(num):
    print(num ** 3)
    time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = 0
    while counter < 10:
        proc1 = Process(target=func1, args=[2])
        proc2 = Process(target=func2, args=[2])
        proc1.start()
        proc2.start()
        proc1.join()
        proc2.join()
        counter += 1
```

once I run it: it prints "Hello" a every loop. I'm sure I'm just making a dumb mistake, but any help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Seems like your code is OK, when I run it, "hello" is only printed once and then 4 & 8 are printed in repeating fashion.

Comment: @Benjamin - Which operating system are you using? You'd get the print a bunch times under Windows that spawns new python instances.

Answer (score 0):

`multiprocessing` can fork an existing process or spawn a new process, depending on which options your operating system supports. On Windows, which can only spawn (execute a new process), a new instance of python is executed. That instance imports the module and then recreates your execution environment by expanding a pickled snapshot of your parent process. Theoretically, just enough to get the environment right for the subprocess.

In your case, `print` is at the module level so it is executed as part of the import in the subprocess. If this was the `"__main__"` module, you can simply put that print in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` clause. When its imported as a module instead of executed as a script, that print won't run.

If its not the main script module, well, that's messy. The general rule for modules is that they should be importable without side effects and that print is a side effect. Best to remove it in that case.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, Thank you for your input!